# Juju - cannot remove unit or application

Tags: juju, maas, openstack

I have a Juju bootstrap cluster running and had an issue with the jenkins charm which caused multiple units to error out. However, after multiple attempts, I am unable to remove any of the errored units.

Additionally, after removing the machine (using the "force" flag) they were meant to deploy on I have issues with other units like keystone which are now stuck in waiting.

Rerunning bootstrap is not an option in this case - as we have devs using VMs at the moment on Openstack.

Things tried:

"juju remove-machine  --force" - does not work on account of the units not being associated with machine

"juju remove-application  --force" - does not work - throws up an issue with the "force" flag.

### Output:

"ERROR option provided but not defined: --force"

Without the force flag it presents the message "removing-application" but nothing changes

"juju remove-unit  --force" does not work - throws up an issue with the "force" flag.

### Output:

"ERROR option provided but not defined: --force"

Without the force flag it presents the message "removing-unit" but nothing changes

I've tried various combinations of "juju resolve" but to no avail.

A link to the screenshot of "juju-status" below:
https://pasteboard.co/IsvdSqo.png

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The `--force` option was only added to Juju recently. It's possible that you're running a version of Juju that doesn't support it. You can check by running `juju help remove-application` and seeing if it references `--force`. Regardless, it shouldn't be necessary.

What is the output of the following?

```
juju remove-application myjenkins
```

How did you deploy the Jenkins charm?

It looks like that you've attempted to deploy it into a LXD container (see the status message: `cannot assign unit "jenkins/2" to machine 1/lxd/3`), which isn't supported.

It also appears that a previous installation attempt to machine 1 hasn't cleaned up things properly and the old mount point is still present. You may need to SSH into the machine and delete the mount point:

```
juju ssh 0
sudo rm /srv/mnt/jenkins
```

You should also remove the other failed applications:

```
juju remove-application jenkins
juju remove-application myjenkins2
```

Now you should be able to deploy Jenkins cleanly:

```
juju deploy jenkins --to 0
```